# How can i know the resolution of an image and How can i change it?

Tags: display-resolution, image-viewers

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 , and need to ensure that the image has a resolution of e.g. 300 pixels-per-inch

I tried to use GIMP but couldn't change or know the exact resolution

[image]

Comment: possibly helpful - https://guides.lib.umich.edu/c.php?g=282942&p=1888164

Comment: "*I tried to use GIMP but couldn't change or know the exact resolution*" Are you asking for a GIMP tutorial? There are already dozens of those on YouTube. What exactly are you asking that those don't answer?

Comment: @user535733 i think my question is clear !! i wrote that i tried to search for a solution like GIMP but couldn't .. I'm really surprise if you are down-vote the post before asking what is the wrong ! if you have a solution .. let me know

Comment: @guiverc thanks for the link .. i tried to follow this link before but couldn't change the resolution

Comment: What type of images are yoiu referring to? Jpegs do not have DPI references for example. Gimp can provide all the size and pixel information available.

Comment: @darth_epoxy .. the images with jpeg extension

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is you can only increase the PPI by shrinking the image.
Open the jpg or jpeg file with GIMP and then from the top menu select
**Image** and then **Image Properties** (Alt+Return)
This will show you the "Size in pixels" and the "Resolution" in PPI.
(DPI or true resolution does not relate to this type of image file)
So from the "Size in pixels" count you can do your own math.